# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable , where does it take an array from?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
def draw_PF(g, x0, nb, colors):    
    plt.plot([x0], [x0], color = colors, marker='o')
    for i in range(nb):
        x1 = g(x0)
        plt.plot([x0,x0], [x0,x1], color = colors)
        plt.plot([x0,x1], [x1,x1], color = colors)
        x0 = x1

x = np.linspace(0,1,999)
y1 = 1-np.sin()
y2 = np.exp(-4*x)
y3 = 0.4 * np.exp() - 0.25
y4 = 1/(1 + ((1-x)/x)**2)
y = x
y1_dev = -np.cos(x)
y2_dev = -4 * y2
y3_dev = 0.4*np.exp(x)
y4_dev = 2*((1 + ((1-x)/x)**2)**-2)*((1-x)/x**3)
functions = [y1,y2,y3,y4]
derivatives = [y1_dev,y2_dev,y3_dev,y4_dev]
iterations = [10,10,10,10]
colors = ["r","g","c","m"]
fixed_points = [0.5,0.3,0.3,0.5]
for i in range(len(functions)):
    plt.plot(x,functions[i])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
for j in range(len(derivatives)):
    plt.plot(x,derivatives[j])
    plt.show()

for k in range(len(functions)):
    dessiner_PF(functions[k],(fixed_points[k] - 0.1), iterations[k], couleurs[k])
    plt.show()
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 25
     22     plt.show()
     24 for k in range(len(functions)):
---> 25     draw_PF(functions[k],(fixed_points[k] - 0.1), iterations[k], colors[k])
     26     plt.show()

Cell In[27], line 15, in draw_PF(g, x0, nb, colors)
     13 plt.plot([x0], [x0], color = colors, marker='o')
     14 for i in range(nb):
---> 15     x1 = g(x0)
     16     plt.plot([x0,x0], [x0,x1], color = colors)
     17     plt.plot([x0,x1], [x1,x1], color = colors)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable``
```

'Hello, I keep receiving this error message, but i dont understand quite why...
I am trying to implement a Picard algorithm to find fix points, but I keep having an issue with my call, I especially don't understand from where it takes the numpy array... thank you in advance.'

Comment: Hi Anna! Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? From what I can see the imports are missing as well as some objects do not have the same name as their definition (`dessiner_PF` vs `draw_PF`, `colors` vs `couleurs`)

Comment: Did you at some point assign `g` to a numpy array and are now trying to use it as a callable: `g = np.array(1)` then doing `g(1)` will raise the same error.

Comment: `functions = [y1,y2,y3,y4]` - this contains 4 numpy.ndarray.

Comment: the error traceback clearly shows that `g(x0)` is the problem.  That's the wrong syntax if `g` is not a `callable`, a function.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from this function:

```
def draw_PF(g, x0, nb, colors):    
    plt.plot([x0], [x0], color = colors, marker='o')
    for i in range(nb):
        x1 = g(x0)  # error is here
        plt.plot([x0,x0], [x0,x1], color = colors)
        plt.plot([x0,x1], [x1,x1], color = colors)
        x0 = x1
```

`g(x0)` does not work because g itself is not defined as a function in your code. If you do `print(g)` you get a `numpy.ndarray` with the shape `(999,)`. This is because you define `y1`, which is the first object representing `g` in `draw_PF`,  as follows:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,999)
y1 = 1-np.sin(x)
```

Since y1 is a numpy array, it is not **callable** (that is to say it does not behave like a function since it's an array) and therefore python returns you this error `numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. The same applies for `y2`, `y3`,  and `y4`.

Let me know if this helped!

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to know for sure, but it seems like `g` is a `np.ndarray`, and you're trying to access element `x0`. In that case, you want `g[x0]`, to access the `x0`'th element of the list.